# Angularjs for inside Controller running just once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to store the ids of an array of objs, but appears that this for loop is running just once, very strange

```
  for (var i = 0; i < softwareIds.length; i++) {
    var b = softwareIds[i].id;
  }

  console.log(b);
  console.log(softwareIds);
```

the last two lines of consoles returns this:
 (number 2 is the first console.log returning the last obj id, and [Object, Object, Object] in the second console.log)

[image]

I'm using angujarJS, this for are inside a Controller, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the array first. see below

```
$scope.b = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < softwareIds.length; i++) {
      $scope.b.push(softwareIds[i].id);
  }

console.log(b);
```

Your for loop is working fine but you are every time overwriting the value stored in the variable. You should push id value in an array.

Comment: Try `<p ng-repeat="item in softwares"> {{ item }}</p>`. It will work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is running three times.  You keep updating the value of b.

Comment: And at the end `b` will store the last value of the array _only_.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using this code inside AngularJS controller doesn't have anything to do with what you are experiencing. This is a common thing, the **console.log(b)** line of code is going to be executed only when the for loop finishes its own thing and when the for loop is finished b variable is going to have the value of the last items id.

Also, in order to store the array of object ids as you need to use an Array, you pretty much answered on this question.

```
var ids = [];

for (var i = 0; i < softwareIds.length; i++) {
    ids.push(softwareIds[i].id);
}
```